# How to weak link a ARC project within a non ARC project

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting, project

I'm using an SDK within my NON ARC app. Unfortunately the SDK is ARC and my own App is non-ARC. Because I added the complete project and not separate `.m` & `.h` files I can't set the specific classes with a Compiler flag `-fobjc-arc`.

How can set these compiler flags for the entire imported project?

[image]

Comment: How did you add the 'complete project'? Was it a framework, static library, Xcode project, etc.?

Comment: an XCode project (AdSDK)

Comment: Can you not add the `-fobjc-arc` flag to the build settings of the MASTAdView project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are compiling the SDK's .m files in your project, then add the `-fobjc-arc` flag to each of the .m files.

If the SDK is already compiled into a library (a `.a` file) or framework which you're simply linking into your project, then you should be able to use it in your non-ARC project without incident. They're undoubtedly following the [rules that ARC enforces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW14), but that is not incompatible with non-ARC project.